# sqlcipher build windows 8

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlcipher

quite new to running code. Am trying to build sqlcipher on Windows 8 using MinGW msys method following this tutorial: http://www.jerryrw.com/howtocompile.php#

All the code seems to run fine to build sqlcipher, but when I go to test it in command prompt, I get this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Owner>cd c:\sqlcipher

c:\sqlcipher>sqlcipher test.db
sqlcipher: FATAL: Couldn't find sqlcipher.
```

Anyone got any ideas? The build should have created an sqlcipher executable dll file and an amalgamated sqlite3.c file. On Searching, have found sqlite3.c but no dll file. Code for build is:

```
./configure --with-crypto-lib=none --disable-tcl CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC    -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -I/c/opensslbuild32/include /c/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll -L/c/sqlcipher/ -static-libgcc" LDFLAGS="-leay32"

make clean
make sqlite3.c
make
make dll
```

As I assume that the error is in the make dll code, here it is:

```
$ make dll
echo 'EXPORTS' >sqlite3.def
nm .libs/sqlite3.o | grep ' T ' | grep ' _sqlite3_' \
            | sed 's/^.* _//' >>sqlite3.def
gcc -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -    I/c/opensslbuild32/include /c
/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll -L/c/sqlcipher/ -static-libgcc -DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1 -I.   -I/
c/sqlcipher/src -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/rtree -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/fts3 - D_HAVE_SQLITE_
CONFIG_H -DBUILD_sqlite -DNDEBUG  -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1   -shared -o  sqlite3.dll
 sqlite3.def \
            -Wl,"--strip-all" .libs/sqlite3.o
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who has same issue, [here](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-build-windows-8/917) is the answer.

Actually everything is correct. Just invoke with sqlcipher.exe instead of sqlcipher because the sqlcipher binary is already existed in somewhere.